# Lenovo Ideapad s400u

Tags: lenovo, compatibility, ideapad

I'm going to buy this machine (Lenovo Ideapad s400u)
Does someone know if it's completely compatible with ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that really there is no **definite** way of knowing.  From experience, and trying different hardware with Ubuntu, I can tell that it will probably work.  Check the [Ubuntu Certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) website to have a better idea.

Comment: Thank you, Mitch. At your link I didn't find this exactly hardware so... if I'm not going to use Win8, should I buy it and to hope it's compatible?

Answer (score 1):

I bought it.
Everything works fine with ubuntu 12.10